# Problems with Mysqli Multiquery and using the results in the proceeding PHP Page

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, output

I'm having some trouble with mysqli multi queries, specifically using them after they have come out of this. If I put the 'printf' line in it will print the averages, but I cannot use the seem to use the arrays outside of the mysqli section [was planning on using them to organise an image on the page below].

I am quite new to PHP and Mysql so I apologise if I have missed something in the previous threads that would have sorted this/pointed me in the right direction - but I'm still struggling with it.

If I am being stupid with this, then feel free to set fire to me and throw me in a bucket of excrement, but whilst previously having 'printf("%s\n", $row[0,1,2,3 etc]);' in it will print the results, but if I try to use row[0] later in the page it uses those characters instead of calling on the value that should be stored there.

```
$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost", "uname", "passwordbit", "mydb");
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

$query = "SELECT AVG(cpcriminalswork) from mydb;";
$query .= "SELECT AVG(cpsentancing) from mydb;";
$query .= "SELECT AVG(cpdeathpenalty) from mydb;";
$query .= "SELECT AVG(cphumanrights) from mydb;";
$query .= "SELECT AVG(cpprotection) from mydb;";
$query .= "SELECT AVG(tbtaxationspread) from mydb;";
$query .= "SELECT AVG(tbtaxmax) from mydb;";
$query .= "SELECT AVG(tbdole) from mydb;";
$query .= "SELECT AVG(tbchildben) from mydb;";
$query .= "SELECT AVG(tbunemployment) from mydb;";
$query .= "SELECT AVG(eebanks) from mydb;";
$query .= "SELECT AVG(eeminwage) from mydb;";
$query .= "SELECT AVG(eeforiegnaid) from mydb;";
$query .= "SELECT AVG(eemilitary) from mydb;";
$query .= "SELECT AVG(eemaxwage) from mydb";

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
do {
    /* store first result set */
    if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        }
        $result->free();
    }
    if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
    }
} while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: is it indeed one table or it's just a sketch that doesn't reflect real life setup?

Comment: The table is up and populated, I've been using the user inputs to the table to output something on the page using the POST data, and I want to use the collected averages to produce an average output on the mian part of the page as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for a Multiquery. You can just collect the AVG's with SQL.

( see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/529e8/3 )

```
$query = "SELECT AVG(foo1) as foo1, AVG(foo2) as foo2, AVG(foo3) as foo3, AVG(foo4) as foo4 from mydb";
$res = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($query));

print_r($res);
```

Output should be something like

foo1 => 3
foo2 => 1
foo3 => 7
foo4 => 9

Comment: Thanks for this! May just have saved my project!